# Como aplicar a condição IF ELSE à seleção de uma coluna?

Tags: mysql, query, condição

Em MySQL, tenho uma tabela antiga `entities` onde a coluna `gender` está com o formato [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html), contendo valores do tipo: "i", "m", "f".

Ao proceder à migração destes dados para a nova estrutura desta tabela, pretendia executar uma consulta à base de dados recolhendo os valores conforme vão ficar na tabela de destino:

### Exemplo:

```
┌─────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ Valor atual │  Valor pretendido  │
├─────────────┼────────────────────┤
│      i      │  undifferentiated  │
├─────────────┼────────────────────┤
│      m      │  male              │
├─────────────┼────────────────────┤
│      f      │  female            │
└─────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Como posso aplicar uma condição `IF ELSE` na seleção desta coluna, indicando o valor pretendido para cada uma das opções existentes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma maneira é aplicar o [operador CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) à selecção da coluna pretendida indicando cada uma das "conversões" a terem lugar:

### Exemplo de consulta:

```sql
SELECT CASE gender
  WHEN 'i' THEN 'undifferentiated'
  WHEN 'm' THEN 'male'
  WHEN 'f' THEN 'female'
END AS gender
FROM `entities`
WHERE 1
```

O que está a ser feito é selecionar a coluna `gender` de todas as linhas da tabela `entities`, onde por cada linha verificamos o valor da mesma e atribuímos o novo valor pretendido.

### Exemplo do resultado:

```
┌────────────────────┐
│  gender            │
└────────────────────┘
┌────────────────────┐
│  undifferentiated  │
├────────────────────┤
│  undifferentiated  │
├────────────────────┤
│  male              │
├────────────────────┤
│  female            │
└────────────────────┘
```